# Android table layout starts from the edge of the phone

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I'm using table layout to show some data but the table starts from the edge of the phone from left to right. How do i do if i want the entire table at the center and some space on right and left. Please advice. Below is my code.

Code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="2" >

        <LinearLayout android:gravity="left" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ezwaybill" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/van" />
        </TableRow>

        <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SENDER"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="22sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Account"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="0001"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:text="Tel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="01111022408615"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:text="Add"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="No. 7, Ferrers Park"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:text="Country"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="Malaysia"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:text="Postcode  "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="44800"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="customer@domain.com"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />    

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code it look like as shown in image
[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <TableLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="2" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout android:gravity="left" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </TableRow>

        <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SENDER"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="22sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="Account"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="0001"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:text="Tel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="01111022408615"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:text="Add"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="No. 7, Ferrers Park"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:text="Country"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="Malaysia"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:text="Postcode  "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="44800"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:padding="2dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText6"
                android:layout_span="2"
                android:editable="false"
                android:text="customer@domain.com"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp" />    

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your main View a Size and set android:layout_gravity="center". (Not sure if this works with Views). So they dont fill the Parent.

Else just give it a

```
android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
```

for example.

best regards